# How to get the ID of the last insert in MVC?

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

I have a `$mydata->save();` in my statement to insert a new row, and the next row in the action I need the `ID` of the inserted row. How can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$myData` is a model then :

```
$result = $myData->save();
$id = $result->id;
```

Kind of same like in Laravel.

Although if you are using some MVC CMS like Joomla then it should be like:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery( $query );
$db->query();

$id = $db->insertid();
```

And also if you have liberty to run raw queries then simply use:

```
mysql_insert_id();
```

So it really depends upon you particular situation.

Comment: No problem :) Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

```
$id=$this->db->insert_id();
```

To get the last inserted id.